# Deleted my user in hkey_users

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-registry, regedit

Windows 7. I've deleted a directory in registry with my user in hkey_users. After that a new one was created automatically but I'm having some issues other than just losing a lot of settings and need an advice on how to fix them.

1. Some mouse settings reset after restart. The most important ones are pointer speed and enhance precision.
2. Right click folder view settings don't save at all. Just opening the same folder again shows me the default  "details" view setting.
3. Can't set some default programs from properties menu even thous I can use them from "open with" just fine.

It would be nice if there was some kind of automatic solution that targets this exact issue in case I have more undiscovered problems.

Comment: Use system restore, pick a date before you deleted the registry entry.

Answer (score 1):

If restoring before the registry change does not recover your profile, log in as an administrator and look for your data in USERS.  Much of the data should be there.

Likely with damage like this, you are going to have to create a new user and set it up again. As I noted you should be able to recover your data.

Worst case, you may need to reinstall Windows.

Comment: I have only one restore point from two days ago but user was deleted for 5 days already so system restore option will not work.

Comment: So my post is basically correct in its major points.